# run an EAS dev-client build on actual device for developing

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, native-module

I recently added an [NPM package for camera](https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor#managed-expo) which impacts the Native Modules, so it's not supported by Expo out of the box.  Now I am sending a build to EAS and then running that IPA file on my Simulator locally.  The issue is that the [VideoCamera is not supported by the iOS simulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)

I am creating a [development build](https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/#on-a-device) which is sent to EAS, as described in my eas.json:

```
"development": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal", // tried with & without this line
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
```

Then I run `npx expo start --dev-client` so that i can tap into the `expo-dev-client` can be hooked into my app.  It runs fine on my simulator, but when needing to access the camera for video, we need to use a physical device due to limitation stated above.

How can I run the EAS image on my physical device?  Or how can I run Expo locally, which can still manage the Native Modules impacted by the new NPM lib?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to register the iOS device and then get the actual build on your physical device?

Comment: my device is registered via `eas:create`...
The build shows up on my device from scanning the QR code, but it's a "prod" environment in Test Flight, not a "development" environment.

is there something else I missed in the docs?  @Nelloverflow

Comment: And would the EAS build allow for development environment on a physical device?

Comment: Yeah that's the whole point of development builds: add native code outside of Expo Go, build and then keep developing on the physical device with the development server

Comment: ok, on the right path...is there documentation i missed so that the actual device picks up the development part of it? 
Does my profile at the top look ok?  Why does the QR code not recognize the app correctly?

Comment: based on docs, https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/#on-a-device, I should get a QR code, but my EAS build only has download option, under`Install` button

Comment: The QR code you are given will land you on the APK for the Android version (the one I've personally tested: I guess with an iOS device you'll get an .ipa or w/e) and after you install it you'll get a similar experience to Expo Go except you'll have the native modules installed and be able to develop with those